# Static files: Images are being loaded but not CSS and JS files | Django

Tags: django, static

I'm trying to load CSS and JS files in my Django templates but it's not working. I could load images succesfully.

My settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_DIR,
)
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
.
.
.
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + \
              static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
   
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

  <link href="{% static 'card-js.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="{% static 'card-js.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <img src="{% static 'bag1.png' %}" width="25px">
```

My file structure:

```
dma
 - account
 - cart
 - dma
 - home
 - media
 - payment
 - static
 - - bag1.png
 - - card-js.min.css
 - - card-js.min.js
```

The image 'bag1.png' is loaded correctly but not the 'css' and 'js' files.

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: That looks right.  Can you view the source code in the browser to see what url is actually rendering?  Try to navigate to it.

Comment: @GAEfan, in the source code: <link href="/static/card-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> and <script src="/static/card-js.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>. I'm wondering the error is because both are inside the <body> and not in the <head> tag.

Comment: That shouldn't matter, except for the sequence of loading.  Can you click on the links in the source code to see if they load?  What platform are you on for hosting?  Do you have an `app.yaml`?

Comment: I don't see `MEDIA_URL` defined in `settings`.  Try: `print(MEDIA_URL)`. 
 Then, `STATIC_URL = MEDIA_URL = '/static/'` They're supposed to be different, but just to test

Comment: Yes, there are both loading in the source code (so weird!). I'm hosting offline (localhost) because I'm building a new part of the website, despite I had upload some files to Heroku last month.Is there any relation with the collect static files?

Comment: # Media settings
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Is it correct?

Comment: If they are loading from the source code, sounds like you need to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Just cleaned the cache and the problem is still on!

Comment: There is some issue with another part of the page because when I exclude all lines but the ones I wrote above, the code runs perfectly. May I have some conflict with the base.html?

Comment: @GAEfan, thank you for helping me: just discovered a duplicated javascript code in base.html. Now everything is working OK.

Answer (score 0):

html content but i think this problem happened when you use your link tag and js tag in body you should do this :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
{% block head %} <!-- for css links --> {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
{% block body %}<!-- for body content -->{% endblock %}
</body>
{% block js %}<!-- for js links -->{% endblock %}
</html>
```

and don't remember rel="" for your links